# How can I make typescript 'type tip' more limited in the code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

typescript tip: step is `any` type. This is too bad!

How do I optimize?

```js
export function foo (isActive:boolean) {
  let step
  if (isActive) {
    step = [
      '1ICK750', '2IYE230', '3CI0320', '3CI0720', '4PGC938'
    ] as const
  } else {
    step = [
      'are', 'by', 'sea', 'seashells', 'she', 'shore', 'the', 'zoo'
    ] as const
  }
  // ...more

  // typescript tip: step is any type.This is too bad!
  return step
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define it using the conditional operator instead.

```
const step = isActive
    ? ['1ICK750', '2IYE230', '3CI0320', '3CI0720', '4PGC938'] as const
    : ['are', 'by', 'sea', 'seashells', 'she', 'shore', 'the', 'zoo'] as const;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the step like this

```
let step: string[] = []
```

now your return type will also be a string of array.